# Android ListView item wrong after scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have a ListView that uses a layout containing a TextView which is a separator.  I have code in place so that if the separator should show, it sets the Visibility to View.VISIBLE, and otherwise View.GONE.  That is working fine, however I noticed the list is only correct the first load.  Once I scroll the list to the bottom and back up it is incorrectly showing/hiding my separator.  I know this is a known programming error with ListViews, but I'm a bit confused on how to tackle it.  Below is my code.  How can I fix this?

```
public class MaintenanceGrid extends Activity {

    static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    static final String KEY_SCHEDULEFLAG = "scheduleflag";
    static final String KEY_LASTSERVICEDATE = "lastservicedate";
    static final String KEY_LASTSERVICEMILEAGE = "lastservicemileage";
    static final String KEY_LASTSERVICEVENDOR = "lastservicevendor";
    static final String KEY_MILEAGEINTERVAL = "mileageinterval";
    static final String KEY_CURRENTODOMETER = "currentodometer";
    static final String KEY_MILEAGEOVERDUE = "mileageoverdue";
    static final String KEY_NEXTMILEAGEDUE = "nextmileagedue";

    AlertDialogManager alertDialog = new AlertDialogManager();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> maintenanceGridList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Globals globals;
    MaintenanceGridData maintenanceGridData;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ListView list;
    MaintenanceGridAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maintenance_grid);
        globals = (Globals) this.getApplication();
        // Set our custom font
        View rootView = findViewById(R.id.layoutMaintenanceGridContainer);
        Globals.applyCustomFont((ViewGroup) rootView, FontClass.Arial(this));

        // Execute main task to get the maintenance grid
        new MaintenanceGridDetails().execute(globals.getCarID());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            globals = (Globals) this.getApplication();
            if(globals.getDriverID()==null){
                Intent i = new Intent(MaintenanceGrid.this, Splash.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            Intent i = new Intent(MaintenanceGrid.this, Splash.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }

    private class MaintenanceGridDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>
    {
        static final int STATUS_SUCCESS = 1;
        static final int STATUS_FAIL = 0;
        static final int STATUS_NETWORK = 3;
        static final int STATUS_ERROR = 2;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getParent(), "", getResources().getString(R.string.general_msg_please_wait));
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            if(!NetworkStatus.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).isOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
                return STATUS_NETWORK;
            }
            maintenanceGridData = MaintenanceGridDetails(params[0]);
            if(maintenanceGridData==null) { return STATUS_ERROR; }
            if(maintenanceGridData.getMaintenanceGridDescription().size()!=0){
                return STATUS_SUCCESS;
            } else {
                return STATUS_FAIL;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
        {
            if (result == STATUS_ERROR)
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                alertDialog.showAlertDialog(getParent(), getResources().getString(R.string.error), getResources().getString(R.string.error_connect), false);
            }
            else
            if (result == STATUS_NETWORK)
            {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Intent networkError = new Intent(MaintenanceGrid.this, NetworkError.class);
                        networkError.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(networkError);
                        finish();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
            else
            if (result == STATUS_FAIL )
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                alertDialog.showAlertDialog(getParent(), getResources().getString(R.string.error), getResources().getString(R.string.maintenance_grid_unavailable), false);
            }
            else
            {
                //set values in hashmap for listview
                for(int x=0; x<maintenanceGridData.getMaintenanceGridDescription().size(); x++)
                {
                    //create new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, maintenanceGridData.getMaintenanceGridDescription().get(x));
                    map.put(KEY_SCHEDULEFLAG, maintenanceGridData.getMaintenanceGridScheduleFlag().get(x));
                    map.put(KEY_LASTSERVICEDATE, maintenanceGridData.getMaintenanceGridLastServiceDate().get(x));
                    map.put(KEY_LASTSERVICEMILEAGE, maintenanceGridData.getMaintenanceGridLastServiceMileage().get(x));
                    map.put(KEY_LASTSERVICEVENDOR, maintenanceGridData.getMaintenanceGridLastServiceVendor().get(x));
                    map.put(KEY_MILEAGEINTERVAL, maintenanceGridData.getMaintenanceGridMileageInterval().get(x));
                    map.put(KEY_CURRENTODOMETER, maintenanceGridData.getMaintenanceGridCurrentOdometer().get(x));
                    map.put(KEY_MILEAGEOVERDUE, maintenanceGridData.getMaintenanceGridMileageOverdue().get(x));
                    map.put(KEY_NEXTMILEAGEDUE, maintenanceGridData.getMaintenanceGridNextMileageDue().get(x));
                    //add history entry to main arraylist
                    maintenanceGridList.add(map);
                }

                list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMaintenanceGrid);

                // Get adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
                adapter = new MaintenanceGridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getParent(), maintenanceGridList);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);    

                //close dialog
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                // If the Status Badge id visible, hide it
                if (Main.statusTabBadge.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Main.statusTabBadge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Globals.ackMaintenanceItemsDue=true;
                        }
                    }, 500);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public MaintenanceGridData MaintenanceGridDetails (final String carid) {
         // method here gets the data for my adapter
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
static class ViewHolderItem {
        TextView lblMaintenanceGridLastServiceDate, lblMaintenanceGridOdometer, lblMaintenanceGridCurrentOdometer, lblMaintenanceGridSeparator,
        description, last_service_date, odometer, current_odometer;
        ImageView imageMaintenanceItemIcon;
    }

 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
        View vi = convertView;
        if(vi==null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maintenance_grid_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.lblMaintenanceGridLastServiceDate = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lblMaintenanceGridLastServiceDate);
            viewHolder.lblMaintenanceGridOdometer = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lblMaintenanceGridOdometer);
            viewHolder.lblMaintenanceGridCurrentOdometer = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lblMaintenanceGridCurrentOdometer);
            viewHolder.lblMaintenanceGridSeparator = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lblMaintenanceSeparator);
            viewHolder.description = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.lblMaintenanceGridDescription);
            viewHolder.last_service_date = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtMaintenanceGridLastServiceDate);
            viewHolder.odometer = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtMaintenanceGridOdometer);
            viewHolder.current_odometer = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtMaintenanceGridCurrentOdometer);
            viewHolder.imageMaintenanceItemIcon = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.maintenanceGridItemIcon);

            // Store the holder with the view
            vi.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) vi.getTag();
        }

        if(position % 2 == 0){
            vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector_even);
        } else {
            vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector_odd);
        }

        // Make the items in this listview NOT clickable
        vi.setEnabled(false);
        vi.setOnClickListener(null);

        HashMap<String, String> maintenanceGridItem = new HashMap<String, String>();
        maintenanceGridItem = data.get(position);

        if(data.get(position) != null) {
            // Show/Hide the separator
            if (!currentMileageInterval.equalsIgnoreCase(maintenanceGridItem.get(MaintenanceGrid.KEY_MILEAGEINTERVAL))) {
                currentMileageInterval = maintenanceGridItem.get(MaintenanceGrid.KEY_MILEAGEINTERVAL);
                viewHolder.lblMaintenanceGridSeparator.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.maintenance_grid_separator_text, currentMileageInterval));
                viewHolder.lblMaintenanceGridSeparator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                viewHolder.lblMaintenanceGridSeparator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            // Setting all values in listview
            viewHolder.description.setText(maintenanceGridItem.get(MaintenanceGrid.KEY_DESCRIPTION));
            viewHolder.last_service_date.setText(maintenanceGridItem.get(MaintenanceGrid.KEY_LASTSERVICEDATE));
            viewHolder.odometer.setText(maintenanceGridItem.get(MaintenanceGrid.KEY_LASTSERVICEMILEAGE));
            viewHolder.current_odometer.setText(maintenanceGridItem.get(MaintenanceGrid.KEY_CURRENTODOMETER));

            // Set up the image
            if (maintenanceGridItem.get(MaintenanceGrid.KEY_SCHEDULEFLAG).equalsIgnoreCase("overdue")) {
                viewHolder.imageMaintenanceItemIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_alert_overdue);
            } else if (maintenanceGridItem.get(MaintenanceGrid.KEY_SCHEDULEFLAG).equalsIgnoreCase("due")) {
                viewHolder.imageMaintenanceItemIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_alert);
            } else {
                viewHolder.imageMaintenanceItemIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_check);
            }

            // Set our custom font
            viewHolder.lblMaintenanceGridLastServiceDate.setTypeface(arialTypeface);
            viewHolder.lblMaintenanceGridLastServiceDate.setTypeface(arialTypeface);
            viewHolder.lblMaintenanceGridOdometer.setTypeface(arialTypeface);
            viewHolder.lblMaintenanceGridCurrentOdometer.setTypeface(arialTypeface);
            viewHolder.lblMaintenanceGridSeparator.setTypeface(arialTypeface, Typeface.BOLD);
            viewHolder.description.setTypeface(arialTypeface, Typeface.BOLD);
            viewHolder.last_service_date.setTypeface(arialTypeface);
            viewHolder.odometer.setTypeface(arialTypeface);
            viewHolder.current_odometer.setTypeface(arialTypeface);
        }

        return vi;
    }
```

Comment: please add your Activity class

Comment: you should at least use the viewHolder pattern for the listview. Example here: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: As you are not using the ViewHolder, try removing these lines  if(vi==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maintenance_grid_item, null); and add vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.maintenance_grid_item, parent, false) instead.

Comment: @VariniRamesh I've updated my code to use the ViewHolder pattern and have updated my code in the question above.  However, the listview loads correctly on first load, and then after I scroll the separator TextViews do not show/hide correctly.  They get mixed up.

Comment: As I can not try the code, its just a guess try adding this line viewHolder.lblMaintenanceGridSeparator.setVisibility(View.GONE); above if(data.get(position) != null)

Comment: @VariniRamesh, tried your suggestion but same result.

Comment: I thought so after seeing your activity code. I did not see it before. My bad. I think the problem is somewhere related to setting currentMileageInterval. Try to  reset  currentMileageInterval in else block.

Comment: @VariniRamesh which else block?  where I'm checking if currentMileageInterval or where I'm checking if vi==null

Comment: while you are checking currentMileageInterval